How to get rid of this certain kind of insect/fly
I have rented a place. It usually gets overwhelmed by this kind of insect/fly:


Tried
So far I have tried, but none worked:

Anti-fly sprays
Keeping the doors closed
incense sticks
Trying to figure out where they come from. But I cannot figure out from where.

I have created an isolated safe room for myself in which I study and sleep. On some nights, the rest of the house gets attacked by an army of them.
What is this insect? I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Taken out the rubbish?

@SolarMike The trash duty is absolutely done very regularly.

This from your picture:

looks, according to the University of Arkansas Division of Agriculture, like a Clogmia albipunctata, also called a "drain fly":

UofA's website:

These flies occur naturally in shaded locations containing moist, decaying organic matter, such as wet wooded areas or swamps.... They mostly inhabit drains that are used infrequently, such as a guest bathroom shower drain, where water collects in a trap and sits for long periods of time. Larvae develop in this stagnant water, feeding on soap scum and other organic sludge occurring on the inside surfaces of drains and plumbing (algae, fungi, bacteria).

They also live in sink drain overflows. We used to have them in a bathroom sink drain overflow. We had to pour bleach water, hot water, other stuff down the overflow opening to clean it out.
UofA's website suggests putting a cup coated with "vegetable oil or petroleum jelly" over drains to catch the flies, so you'd know if they're in that drain. (We also had to tape the overflow hole.)
Their website also suggests foaming chemical cleansers or a high-pressure drain cleaning service to clean out the schmutz the flies live on. (I'd consider a pressure washer on reasonable pressure, maybe, down the drain and overflow holes.)

It is worth adding that these can be/are often a symptom of a leaking sewer somewhere inaccessible.

What I do every day is pour my cat water into the house sewer drains each morning refill the cat water bowls and also run each sink and flush each toilet to refill the traps. Just being me and a cat in the house those plumbing fixtures aren't normally used each day hence the specific exercising them. Fresh water seems a bane to small insects and their population has crashed even sadly the friendly house spiders.

@j4nd3r53n Actually I guess so. That seems correct.
